# Tell me why marijuana is haram?

Tags: uloom-al-hadith, science

Please I want only strong reasons.  Preferably from those who understand brain chemistry.

I don’t believe marijuana is haram in low doses and moderate use.

The religion teaches us anything bad for us is harm. Well repetition that leads to harm is haram.  Like drinking soda constantly is harmful by itself.

Marijuana (thc) is a psychoactive drug and so is caffeine which apparently  isn’t haram

Marijuana clearly works very differently and on different receptors.  But interestingly enough marijuana enhances grey matter and this has been shown in studies.

Grey matter is in fact responsible for an increase in motor control. Something animals like gorillas lack.

In high amounts marijuana can definitely intoxicate .    Then again in high doses of water and I mean a lot of water.  That Is straight up toxic.

When I have used marijuana in very minor amounts, I have increased cognition and critical thinking goes off the charts!   In fact thc is known to cause the brain to fire all neurons.   Guess what also acts very similarly to THC in many ways, Progesterone! A hormone naturally made in our bodies.

Sure marijuana can affect hormone balance and cause harm but hell so can plastics, soy and xenoEstrogens.

MDMA increases serotonin in the brain, has many negative effects as well as the mental pleasing effects.  But all will say it’s haram.  Well mdma doesn’t dull senses rather it increases them!
(Please don’t do MDMA)

Naicin a necessary vitamin, aka vitamin b3 in megadoses, will cause red flushing and in fact cause serotonin to rise in the brain and have a very similar effect like mdma but for a seriously short period of time.  Is naicin haram?

It seems to me Islam today is being held hostage by those who think they have a sense of moral superiority.

Not just that we seem to taboo things instantly if it shares similarities or links to things we know are very bad things.  When in fact it’s not taboo but helpful.

This is not how intelligent people should be operating.

Hell here is an example of this behavior I am talking about. 
Many people in the US probably think GMOs are bad yet it’s a completely irrational fear that is hindering our own human evolution. Simply because we think of GMOs like pesticides or categorize them in a similar way.   That’s not rational thinking and that’s not smart.

Marijuana is not haram. It’s how you use it that can make it haram just like practically everything.

Comment: This doesn't look like a question, but like a statement.

Comment: Of course it’s a question.  The body was used as a statemen to explain my understanding

Comment: An intoxicant (سكر) is a substance that clouds the intellect, it does not mean that it is toxic. There is a hadith that whatever intoxicates in a large quantity is also haram to consume in a small quantity. ما أسكر كثيره فقليله حرام

Comment: https://www.inc.com/cynthia-than/the-surprising-way-to-be-better-at-brain-teasers-a.html


Marijuana increase cognitive function.   That means it can increase intellect.    This is real science I also talked about how I experience this in my question. .  It’s very frustrating that people Arent adhering to facts.   We are blindly following people and their opinions. This is not Islam. Smh

Answer (score -2):

Everything which is harmful or damageful is haram by default, however a substance that appeared a few decades ago is deemed halal or haram according to what the scholars know it to be. Coca-cola is harmful to the body, yet no fatwa  has been passed against it because scholars don't know what's inside it, and conventionally it is not seen as haram either. Now, when a particular substance is deemed haram is considered so either because it is really harmful, or because scholars base their verdicts upon societal conventions and tribal conventions, even if it is not harmful at all. 
I do not know about marijuana, but you can't expect scholars from Saudi Arabia (all respect towards them) to issue a verdict favouring the smoking of marijuana because they've been raised in a widely known mindset and you yourself know how Saudi elders are. 
Let's assume that in the next year some flavourish smoke-vaping 
mouth device which is harmless and it's proven to be so takes wide market, and scholars them selves were to notice that it is going to become a trend..Will you think that they'll not pass a fatwa against it? Of course they will!!! Hope you got the concept.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification for the purposes of improving the post they're on, not for argument and debate or extended discussion of tangential points. If the relevant posts are unclear to the point that you need extensive discussion to explain how it answers the question, chances are the post needs to be edited.